# How to apply dimensional analysis to solve the problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, dimensional-analysis

There is no question here now as the question was completely misleading.
You can [click here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/152804/shush?tab=profile) to see some questions?

Comment: The homework and exercises tag covers any form of routine problem solving, regardless of whether it was actually set as homework or not.

Comment: [This is my interpretation of the policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange/9080#9080).

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick edited the question

Comment: Dimenisonal analysis can only give you an answer up to a dimensionless constant. It cannot help you decide between the two forms you have shown.

Comment: It can be done.@nick

Comment: How? How can you know just by looking at units whether or not there is a factor of $2\pi$ missing?

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** necessarily answer every question using dimensional analysis. Often, you will need to apply physical interpretations and constraints to get to the final answer. As such, this is a good example of such a case where dimensional analysis cannot help you to get to the final answer.